# Cannot build with error `Server terminated abruptly`

Tags: build, bazel

can not build with server terminated message.

Comment: What are the contents of the `/home/elin/.cache/bazel/_bazel_elin/d60cb132a54ad1843b095cb9690d01e0/server/jvm.out` file from the error message? That should have more information.

Comment: When this error is raised, that log file is empty.

Answer (score 7):

The most common cause I've seen for this kind of thing (can't say for sure without the `jvm.out`) is running out of memory which results in the [OOM killer](https://www.kernel.org/doc/gorman/html/understand/understand016.html) terminating the bazel server process. Between the bazel server process and a bunch of C++ compilations in parallel, it's easy to run out. Using a lower [`--jobs`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--jobs) is the most direct way to limit that. [`--local_ram_resources`](https://docs.bazel.build/versions/master/user-manual.html#flag--local_%7Bram,cpu%7D_resources) will help in theory, but bazel doesn't have a very good idea how much RAM each compilation command uses so it's very approximate.

Comment: Really, So @Eileen_Lin if the problem was solved, accept @Brians' answer. I'm going to try the same approach. By the way `--jobs` only makes the process to be slow until the error is shown up again. But i'm going to follow the approach of cleaning the memory cache.

Comment: I just cleaned my cache using s`ync && echo 3 | sudo tee /proc/sys/vm/drop_caches`, but the problem persists. How did you do that @Eileen_Lin.

Comment: For me, adding `--jobs=1` to the bazel command solved the problem

Comment: using -- local_ ram_ Resources = 40960 to limit the memory size to 40GB. Usually this is error raises when insufficient memory.